# Sydney to Perth on the Indian Pacific, what is included?

Tags: trains, australia, sydney, perth

I will probably take the Indian Pacific from Sydney to Perth in February, and was wondering if anyone has taken the train before. Most likely will be travelling in "Red Service Sleeper Cabin" (3rd class?).

I had a look on tripadvisor.com but could not find any (good) pictures for the cabins. Do they have power outlets in the cabins or lounge there so I can charge my camera or laptop during the trip, or is this only available in 2nd and first class? Is there anything else I should bring for the trip that makes the journey easier or more pleasant?

is there any advantage in booking ahead, or can I just show up on the station and buy the tickets for the next train?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Red Service Sleeper Cabin" is 2nd class and they indeed have power outlets. At least in 2007 I charged my laptop to watch movies on the train.

I heard beforehand that the food isn't that great at least not worth the money, so I brought food to cater myself. Bring a book and lots of movies/series to watch.

I'm not sure about the booking ahead. I just provide you links to [fares](http://www.greatsouthernrail.com.au/site/indian_pacific/fares_2012_2013.jsp) and [timetable](http://www.greatsouthernrail.com.au/site/indian_pacific/timetables_schedules.jsp).

[image]

source: http://www.greatsouthernrail.com.au